# Who makes standards in a programming language such as C++?

Tags: c++, conventions

Do the conventions in a programming language such as in C++ (such as extraction operator >> ) can be changed by a developer? Or is it restricted?

Comment: You can write a preprocessor, or your own compiler, or just override the `>>` operator. To answer your title question, there is a committee that proposes and votes on language standards.

Comment: [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Comment: @DavidLively - What write your own compiler etc.? So nobody else can understand or write the code.....

Comment: If you want to change the behavior of the C++ standard language, you are welcome to submit a proposal to the C++ committee for review.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're asking two questions here.

1. Who makes the C++ Standard?

   [The C++ Standards Committee](https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee)
2. Can I change the behavior of an operator such as `operator>>`?

   Yes, you can, via a capability defined in the standard. See:

   - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators
   - [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/24874)

Comment: So, if that committee brings some new changes to the standards, would every complier maker for that language have to introduce those changes to their compilers?

Comment: @XaibuGemi They will *if* they want to be compatible with the new version of the language. C++ is modified and published in discrete versions every few years. The current model seems to be based on a release every 3 year.

Comment: @XaibuGemi: "Have to" isn't the way to phrase it.  It's a combination that a portion of consumers will want compilers compliant to specific standards or other specific features, and the product owners will be motivated to be relevant to their consumers.

Comment: @XaibuGemi: There's no law specifying that compiler vendors have to implement every new change within 180 days of release, or anything like that. Nonetheless, the main C++ compilers (gcc, clang and to a lesser degree MS VC++) often implement new features even before the committee has finalized the standard to require them.

Comment: Yes, if the changes are part of the standard and the compiler maker wants to represent a "Standards Compliant Compiler", The do not have to implement proposed "extensions" to the standard.

Comment: @Xaibu - You should note that all the major "compiler makers" are members of the committee, so it is not that any new designs are added as a surprise or against everyone's will. The idea is to agree on how to make the language work the same for all compilers. Doing so benefits everyone.